# redefine starred command \section*

Tags: macros, sectioning, titlesec

with `\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}` I have defined `\section` like

```
\titleformat{\section}
  {\ttfamily\Large\bfseries\color{red}}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {#1}
```

i want to redefine the starred version of section `\section*` To become like `\section` (with number) Except that the text after Comes in front of section heading (run in)

Comment: You don't need the `explicit` option: remove it and just leave the last argument empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a `numberless` key (to be used with `name`) that does the  job:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}%
\usepackage{titletoc} %

\titleformat{\section}
  {\ttfamily\Large\bfseries\color{red}}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {#1}%
%
\titleformat{name = \section, numberless}
  {\ttfamily\Large\bfseries\color{red}}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}#1}%

\begin{document}

\section{A Numbered Section}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\section*{An Unnumbered Section}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\section{Still Another Numbered Section}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \section*  with section number and run in mode

Comment: I misunderstood. OK, I'll modify at once.

Comment: @seloumi: I updated my answer, but there will be problems if you want a table of contents.

Comment: by `unnumbered` you mean `numberless`, right? :)

Comment: Yes. I wanted to make a difference between the meaning and the key that's used.

Comment: @Bernard which is quite confusing. I was *sure* it was a typo because the code formatting suggested that the key was actually named `unnumbered`. Only if one studies your code it becomes clear that there actually is *no* key `unnumbered`!

Comment: @cgnieder: Actually, I didn't get you were pointing a typo. One never re-reads oneself enough… Thanks a lot, it's corrected.

Comment: @Bernard I *thought* you meant to type `numberless` when you typed `unnumbered`. Anyway, after your edit all is fine with me :)

Comment: I thought too. But it happens I think several things at a time…;)

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need a table of contents you can delete the lines for the toc redefinition. However a solution with a special macro like `\Ssection}` maybe a better choice, then `\ţableofcontents` hasn't to be redefined:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}%
\let\TableOfContents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{{\titleformat{\section}%
   {\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{##1}\let\section\Section\TableOfContents}}
\let\Section\section
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@ifstar\starsection\Section}
\makeatother
\newcommand\starsection[1]{%
  \par\bigskip\noindent\refstepcounter{section}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\thesection\hspace{0.8em}#1}%
  {\ttfamily\Large\bfseries\textcolor{red}{\thesection\hspace{1em}#1}\hspace{1em}}}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\ttfamily\Large\bfseries\color{red}}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {#1}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A Numbered Section}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\section*{An Unnumbered Section}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a solution if one wants `\contentsname` be typeset ‘ normally’?

Comment: sure. Redefine `\titleformat`